# Old Kernel Module Persistent After Reboot

Tags: linux-kernel, centos

Running CentOS 7

Installed a vendors kernel module

I added a file in "/etc/modules-load.d/loadMyModule" with the module name in it.

After modification, recompile, and reinstall of the module, the old version is persistent on the system after a reboot.

However if I run...

```
sudo modprobe -r mydriver
sudo modprobe mydriver
```

The new version is now working...

How is the old version still getting loaded at boot?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much headbanging

If you have rebuilt the initramfs via dracut, the old module will be there.  After installing the updated module, be sure to re-run dracut so it is replaced in the initramfs

Comment: Found the same issue (unsurprisingly I guess) with RHEL8, seems a bit of an oversight to me that you have to do this extra step.